# How to get check for current month in Daterangepicker?

Tags: javascript, calendar, daterangepicker, angular-daterangepicker

I want to do something like this, I tried multiple ways but I am unable to find it. I am getting start and end date but not the current month. I want current month so it works with all locale

```
if(CURRENT MONTH){
  // Do This
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the Date object for get month as follows,

```
var date = new Date(); // assume date is 10/06/2020
var month = date.getMonth(); // it return month as 10
```

if you want to get month name, firstly you should declare the array including with months and then get the month name using this array as follows,

```
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
var date = new Date(); // assume date is 10/06/2020
var nameOfMonth = months[date.getMonth()-1] // it return month name as October
```

then you can use `month` or `nameOfMonth` as follows,

```
if (month == 10){
    // Do This
}

if (nameOfMonth == 'October'){
    // Do This
}
```